# mocha - command line - do we need quote for test files

Tags: javascript, npm, mocha.js

I have npm scripts like these

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha tools/testSetup.js src/**/*.spec.js"
}

"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha tools/testSetup.js 'src/**/*.spec.js'"
}

"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.spec.js\""
}
```

As you can see, one test script have quote, one has double quote and one has no quote at all. But when run, all of them will perform smoothly as expected. So do we really need to us the quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command is standard bash command. If there isn't space in bash parameter no quotes are needed.